# How to Speed up the DNN Site

Tags: asp.net, performance, dotnetnuke

Can any one give me an idea how to speed up my DNN Site? I have already changed settings in siteSetting Option and cached the site.  But my site is still slow. Can any one help me...

Thanks in Advance

Comment: why two people Downvote this question without leaving any comment for it?

Comment: What version of DNN are you running? What version of IIS?

Answer (score 1):

Pradeep,

Many aspects of the performance are mentioned [here](http://mitchelsellers.com/blogs/2008/04/15/dotnetnuke-performance-settings-explained!.aspx). Along with the cache settings at host settings > performance level. If you are using text/html module, you should use caching in the module settings as well. There are many other things to consider that is explained in detain in that blog post.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any custom modules? I recently deployed an extranet dnn site and the login and home page were extremely slow, all other pages were fast.

Turns out a 3rd party module on the home page was the culprit.